# How do I read a file with special characters, in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I currently have a file that has a special character ^M inside it.

```
Bugs,^MMember Name,Entity Number^MPilgrim,1 404 765 909^MLovene,1 406 373 405^MLarry,1 404 867 143^MTom,^MChristine,1 404 803 973^MJacqueline,1 406 053 064
```

when i try to read this file only the last line is output: Jacqueline,1 406 053 064.  I have the follwoing andit does not work?

```
file.each {|line| puts line }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^M` you're talking about is the [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character with value 0x0d. You can get rid of it using

```
File.read("filename").gsub "\r", ''
```

or split file's contents with it

```
File.read("filename").split "\r"
```

As pointed out by LBg, some platforms, e.g. Windows, require you to open a file in binary mode to read CR characters.

```
File.read("filename", "rb").split "\r"
```

Comment: To read `"\r"` properly you must open in binary mode: `File.open("filename", "rb"){|f| f.read }.split("\r")`.

Comment: Yes, but that's true only for Windows. POSIX platforms ignore 'b' (cf. [man fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)).